# The Badges icon should be linked (to badges)

Tags: feature-request, badges

At the top of a site you see this:

[image]

The arrow: shows a chart and links to your recent activity.

Your username: Links to your profile

The rep count: Links to the reputation tab of your profile

It would make sense if the badges would link to the badges tab of your profile!

Opinions?

Comment: Now that the rep score links to something it makes sense.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I agree!  Everything else on that bar makes sense:

- the envelope takes you to your
  notifications,
- your name takes you to your profile
  page
- your points takes to your "powers"
  list
- your badges *should* take you to the badges page

After all, newbies, when they earn a badge and see it up there next to everything else, will wonder what it is, and **click on it to no avail...**

Comment: Isn't there a giant thingadongdong that tells you "You just won this badge" and tells you what question you even got it on, if applicable?

Comment: @Grace Note: yes there is, but that *notifies* you that you have *earned* a badge, and tells you how you earned it - it doesn't show a list of earned badges or all the badges one can earn or anything like that...

Comment: The OP is saying your badges "should link to your badges sections", not the overall badges page as you say (which is already present about 75 pixels further down, anyway).

Answer (score 7):

Once upon a time there was a boy with a few medals. He didn't have many, but they were cherished possessions and never failed to **please** him.

The boy earned the medals through skill and hard work, and he was proud of them. When he looked at them, they would always **create** a feeling of happiness within his breast.

He kept the medals in a box, which was tied in a bag, which was stored in an attic. Each time he wanted to look at them he climbed the stairs to the attic, untied the bag, opened **the** box, and smiled.

One day, the boy realized that there was no need to keep his box in the attic. He could keep it near him in his room. He further realized that there was no need to keep the medals in a bag *and* a box. He removed the bag so that he could access them as easily as possible.

Now the boy is happy, and his emotional **link** to his medals is stronger than ever.

Comment: Later that week a thief broke into his house, saw the medals, and stole them.  "I guess I should have kept my medals safe in the attic or maybe in a safe," thought the boy with sadness.  (**+1** for the story, which made me smile.)

Comment: +1 for bolded words creating a sentence in a story :D

Answer (score 1):

There already is a link to see your badges: your name takes you to your profile.  What do you want a link on the badges to do, just scroll down that page?

Merely because we *can* link from something doesn't mean we *should.*  In this case, I don't see any benefit to duplicating a link that already exists 50 pixels left.

Comment: If you are Jon Skeet, it is 60 pixels.

Comment: @Ladybug: I thought he wrote a userscript to hide it completely because it was distraction while answering.

Comment: @Roger: He is much too vain to do that.