# Make the badge counts in the navigation bar a link to the list of badges on my profile

Tags: feature-request, badges, navigation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The Badges icon should be linked (to badges)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67875/the-badges-icon-should-be-linked-to-badges)

The badge counts in the navigation bar should be a link to my badges.

[image: screenshot]

As of writing, there is no anchor for the Badges section on a user's profile. There should be, and this should link to it.

Comment: Seconded. Maybe even on the user panel on the bottom of each post as well.

Comment: I don't think the profile has anchors for these things, so a link to badges wouldn't be any different than a link to the profile.

Comment: Indeed it doesn't. That's kind of part of this bug report. I'm on my phone now but someone else can feel free to edit that in if you like.

Comment: It could also link to the "badges" subtab of the profile's "activity" tab. I think I'd like that even better.